# Microsoft bot framework chatbot does not respond on Facebook Messenger and webchat

Tags: facebook, azure, botframework, chatbot

I created a Microsoft Bot Framework, deployed it to Azure, enabled 'AlwaysOn' and added app insights.

My bot answers properly via emulator and Skype (feel free to check out: https://join.skype.com/bot/1cd7d3bf-9c54-486e-9c63-fb5d9fa0895f).

- For Facebook (https://www.facebook.com/teamdarebot/) I get no
  response and `There was an error sending this message to your bot:
  HTTP status code GatewayTimeout` in the dashboard. The app and
  webhooks seem to be configured properly, it is published.
- For mail (teamdareapp.bot@outlook.com) I get no response and no errors.
- For webchat I get no response and `There was an error sending this
  message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout` in the
  dashboard.

I attached debugger to remote bot and I can see this timeouts but I can see many `200` as well, for last two hours (8pm - 10.30 pm) I have 77 `200` and 15 exceptions, mostly timeouts.

I don't use any external APIs or LUIS. The bot does simple logic and pings database. Successful requests usually returns in circa 1 second; sometimes, when bot returns more messages via emulator it's up to 4 seconds.

Any ideas where to look for help or what to correct?

Comment: Very hard to tell without any code to be seen. Did it ever work on fb? Like when you were testing it locally?

Comment: It did worked some months ago, even after publishing. Locally on fb - you mean when in developer mode? I checked that yesterday and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/ignacy130/Teamdare_SO . Main project is Teamdare.Bot. Credentials to db, bot and app insights (hopefully) removed ;)

Comment: Your app id and password should be changed (since they are exposed here: https://github.com/ignacy130/Teamdare_SO/blob/dev/Teamdare.Bot/Communications/Responses.cs )

Comment: @EricDahlvang - thanks champ!